# insert a hyphen into a string C++

Tags: c++, string

i have an array of strings of phone numbers, and i have to insert hyphens into them. what string function should i use, and how?
thanks. :D

Comment: Is this a homework question? Where do you want to have the hyphen? Give an example of an input phone-number and its corresponding output phone-number.

Comment: Are your strings `std::string` instances, or `char*` s ?

Comment: yeah, it's a homework assignment
3823920578 = 382-392-0578

Comment: @Andrei So many of them tonight!

Answer (score 2):

Use STL string functions. Iterate over the array of strings, and for each string, do this:

```
str_num = str_num.substr(0,3) + "-" + str_num.substr(3,3) + "-" + str_num.substr(6,4);
```

EDIT: You can use `insert()` as well, I think that would be a better way.

Comment: That's really inefficient, it makes several unnecessary copies of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I won't give the answer away, but the simplest thing to do is to use the [`std::string::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) method, assuming you're doing C++.

For C strings, you'll have to manually copy the characters around.  I would probably use `sprintf`.

Comment: strncat would be the more useful C-style string function.

Comment: You'd need at least three separate calls to `strcat` or similar, or you could do something like `sprintf(buf, "%.3s-%.3s-%.4s", s, s+3, s+6)`.  Just a question of style, really.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to add two characters to each string, in two specific positions.

Create a function that takes a single phone number string and adds the hyphens where appropriate. This is a good example where it's easy to just use string concatenation, but it's a bad habit. Instead, you can use `string::insert()` to place the hyphens where appropriate.

Once you have this simple function written all you have to do is iterate over the array and apply the function on each element. Coincidentally the `for_each()` function can do just that. You will find it in `<algorithm>`.

```
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>

void with_hyphens(string& phone)
{
    // as explained above
}

// ...
{
    for_each(array, array + ARRAY_LENGTH, &with_hyphens);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `strtok` function to split it into tokens.

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

Comment: You can't split a without a delimiter. Where is the delimiter in a 10-digit number to split it to (3,3,4) digits ?

Comment: @Joy Dutta I agree, but when I posted the answer something else was on my mind. Now I would have used iterators.